# std function constructor initialization

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have started trying to learn std::function after reading Scott Meyers Effective C++. I made the following sample program to give a std::function object to a class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

class FlyBehaviour
{
  public :
  void fly()
  {
    std::cout<<"Flying";
    /* Work Here */
  }
};

typedef std::function<void(const FlyBehaviour&)> FlyFunc;

class Duck
{
  public :
  Duck(FlyFunc flyFunc) : _flyFunc(flyFunc){}

  private :

  FlyFunc _flyFunc;
};

int main()
{
  Duck(&FlyBehaviour::fly);
}
```

Compiling the above code gives me the following error

```
error: invalid use of qualified-name 'FlyBehaviour::fly'
```

On research, most of the internet points to using std::bind/boost::bind as a solution. Can someone please tell me how to apply it, especially where do I need to declare the object to which function is binded?

Comment: What solutions did your research reveal? You're really close but this has been asked so many times... _"where do I need to declare the object"_ Wherever you like?

Answer (score 2):

You need to either `bind` a `FlyBehaviour` object to the std::function or supply a `FlyBehavior` when calling the function. Here is an example of the former (note that I changed the typedef!):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

class FlyBehaviour
{
  public :
  void fly()
  {
    std::cout<<"Flying";
    /* Work Here */
  }
};

typedef std::function<void()> FlyFunc;

class Duck
{
  public :
  Duck(FlyFunc flyFunc) : _flyFunc(flyFunc){}
  void run() {_flyFunc();}

  private :

  FlyFunc _flyFunc;
};

int main()
{
    FlyBehaviour f;
  Duck d(std::bind(&FlyBehaviour::fly, f));
  d.run();
```

Here, `FlyBehaviour::fly`'s signature is `void(FlyBehaviour&)`, but I used `std::bind` to bind a `FlyBehaviour` object to the first argument, making it a `void()` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. In my earlier typedef, was my signature then  void (FlyBehaviour&, FlyBehaviour&) ?

Comment: No, your original typedef would work, but you would need to pass a `FlyBehaviour` object to call the function.